# Period of the sum/product of two functions

Tags: periodic-functions

Suppose that period of $f(x)=T$ and period of  $g(x)=S$, I am interested  what is  a period of $f(x) g(x)$? period of $f(x)+g(x)$? What I have tried is to search in internet, and found following [link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080921043151AAYZ0f8) for this.

Also I know that period of $\sin(x)$ is  $2\pi$, but what about $\sin^2(x)$? Does it have period again $\pi n$, or? example is following function
$y=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos(x)}$
i can do following thing, namely  we know  that  $\sin(x)/\cos(x)=\tan(x)$ and period of tangent function is $\pi$, so I can represent
$y=\sin^2(x)/\cos(x)$ as $y=\tan(x)\times\sin(x)$,but how can calculate period of this?

Please help me.

Comment: The period of $\sin(x)$ is not $\pi n$, but rather $2 \pi$. See this [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+sin+x) on W|A.

Comment: right thanks,thanks for correction

Comment: Just use the definition of the period.

Comment: try $lcm$ of periods.

Comment: it is for  multiplication yes?for summation i think it would be gcd  right?but what about  tg(x)*sin(x)?

Comment: What do you mean by lcm and gcd, this only makes sense for integers. Note that the sum/product of periodic functions isn't necessarily periodic, e.g. if $f$ has period 1 and $g$ has period $\sqrt{2}$ then $f+g$ and $fg$ are not periodic.

Comment: @dato: It doesn't really matter what the operation is -- if you have $h(f(x),g(x))$ for any $h$ that combines $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, you need the least common multiple of the periods. (Except in pathological cases where $h$ ignores one or both of its arguments completely or partially -- then the period of $h(f,g)$ can be some integral quotient of the lcm).

Comment: @Mercy: Least common multiples and greatest common divisors make plenty of sense for non-integers. They may not always _exist_ if the two inputs are non-commensurable reals, but it is well-defined whether they do.

Comment: If the quotient $T/S$ is irrational $h(f,g)$ is not periodic!

Comment: suppose that our periodic are measurable,then for  summation and multiplication have to we use gcd and lcm?

Comment: what if rational?

Comment: @dato: There is never any case where gcd is relevant here (except perhaps sometimes by accident).

Comment: how can i find  site for  understand  how can i calculate periods of such functions

Answer (score 104, accepted):

We make a few comments only.

1. Note that $2\pi$ is a period of $\sin x$, or, equivalently, $1$ is a period of $\sin(2\pi x)$.
   But $\sin x$ has many other periods, such as $4\pi$, $6\pi$, and so on.  However, $\sin x$ has no (positive) period *shorter* than $2\pi$.
2. If $p$ is a period of $f(x)$, and $H$ is **any** function, then $p$ is a period of $H(f(x))$.  So in particular, $2\pi$ is *a* period of $\sin^2 x$.  However, $\sin^2 x$ has a period which is smaller than $2\pi$, namely $\pi$. Note that $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$, so $\sin^2(x+\pi)=\sin^2 x$. It turns out that $\pi$ is the shortest period of $\sin^2 x$.
3. For sums and products,  the general situation is complicated. Let $p$ be a period of $f(x)$ and let $q$ be a period of $g(x)$. Suppose that there are positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $ap=bq=r$. Then $r$ is a period of $f(x)+g(x)$, and also of $f(x)g(x)$.

   So for example, if $f(x)$ has $5\pi$ as a period, and $g(x)$ has $7\pi$ as a period, then $f(x)+g(x)$ and $f(x)g(x)$ each have $35\pi$ as a period.  However, even if $5\pi$ is the shortest period of $f(x)$ and $7\pi$ is the shortest period of $g(x)$, the number $35\pi$ need not be the shortest period of $f(x)+g(x)$ or $f(x)g(x)$.

   We already had an example of this phenomenon: the shortest period of $\sin x$ is $2\pi$, while the shortest period of $(\sin x)(\sin x)$ is $\pi$.  Here is a more dramatic example. Let $f(x)=\sin x$, and $g(x)=-\sin x$.  Each function has smallest period $2\pi$.  But their sum is the $0$-function, which has every positive number $p$ as a period!
4. If $p$ and $q$ are periods of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively, then any common multiple of $p$ and $q$ is a period of $H(f(x), g(x))$ for *any* function $H(u,v)$, in particular when $H$ is addition and when $H$ is multiplication. So the least common multiple of $p$ and $q$, if it exists, is a period of $H(f(x),g(x))$. However, it need not be the *smallest* period.
5. Periods can exhibit quite strange behaviour. For example, let $f(x)=1$ when $x$ is rational, and let $f(x)=0$ when $x$ is irrational. Then every positive rational $r$ is a period of $f(x)$.  In particular, $f(x)$ is periodic but has no shortest period.
6. Quite often, the sum of two periodic functions is not periodic. For example, let $f(x)=\sin x+\cos 2\pi x$.  The first term has period $2\pi$, the second has period $1$. The sum is not a period. The problem is that $1$ and $2\pi$ are *incommensurable*. There do not exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ such that $(a)(1)=(b)(2\pi)$.

Comment: Another potential problem can occur when we *do* have commensurable periods. Consider $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $g(x)=x-\sin(x)$, for instance.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I do not understand the $x-\sin x$, since it does not have a period.

Comment: /facepalm/ That was supposed to be $1-\sin(x)$. Of course the constant function $f+g$ is then periodic, but it is periodic of all periods.

Comment: @CameronBuie: I had already given a very similar example in the answer, with $\sin x$ and $-\sin x$.

Comment: Ah. I see now that you have. Apologies for wasting your time.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Actually, my thanks should be to you. I looked back to see whether my memory was right, and found a bad typo.

Comment: @André Nicolas thanks  very much,what about if we have  fraction of two function?can we  consider  this fraction as inverse of multiplication and  for calculating period use rule of multiuplication?

Comment: @Dato: Division is the same, it is covered by item $4$, where $H(u,v)=u/v$.

Comment: thanks for so fast  comment,i understood everything,unfortunately  in my book where this question was asked,there  was not explained such  situation such as  period of two function multiplication,division and so on

Comment: @Dato: It can be figured out. For if $f(x+p)=f(x)$ and $g(x+p)=g(x)$  then $H(f(x+p), g(x+p))=H(f(x),g(x))$.

Comment: @dato: You are welcome.  Things are not too complicated as long as we are talking about **a** period. But we can construct weird functions $f$ that have multiple periods that cannot be compared easily.

Comment: @curryage: I am typo-prone, but am relieved there isn't a typo in the second property. I really mean $H(f(x))$. In the specific example, we have $f(x)=\sin(x)$ and $H(y)=y^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: In regard to point 4, is there any confirmation that the sum of 'simple' sinusoids, of the form $Asin(mx) + Bsin(nx) + ...$ will have it's 'smallest' period equal to the LCM of periods of each constituent sinusoid?

Comment: Yes, for $A$ and $B$ both non-zero, and integers $m$ and $n$, the (smallest) period can be computed using the lcm.

Comment: Very well written and truly illuminating answer :)

Comment: I would add that even if your two functions have minimal periods which are not commensurable, it is still possible that their sum might be periodic by accident (with a totally unrelated period).  Indeed, it takes a decent amount of cleverness to prove that $f(x)=\sin x+\cos 2\pi x$ really isn't periodic.

Comment: what about fractional periods? so if f(x) has period a/b and g(x) has period c/d, where a,b,c,d are integers what are the periods of (i) f(x)+g(x), (ii) f(x)*g(x) ?

Answer (score 4):

If you are suppose to find period of sum of two function such that, $f(x)+g(x)$ given that period of $f$ is $a$ and period of $g$ is $b$ then period of total $f(x)+g(x)$ will be $\operatorname{LCM} (a,b)$.
But this technique has some constrain as it will not give correct answers in some cases. One of those case is, if you take $f(x)=|\sin x|$ and $g(x)=|\cos x|$, then period of $f(x)+g(x)$ should be $\pi$ as per the above rule but, period of $f(x)+g(x)$ is not $\pi$ but $\pi/2$.
So in general it is very difficult to identify correct answers for the questions regarding period. 
Most of the cases graph will help.

Comment: But technically, in your example, $\pi$ is still a period of f(x)+g(x), it just so happens not to be the smallest period.

Comment: what about multiplication?