# Period of trigonometric function $f(x)=\cos(ax) + \sin(bx)$

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry

> How would you find the period of $$f(x)=\cos(ax) + \sin(bx)$$

*Edit such that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

A step by step proof would be appreciated!

Comment: Let $a = 1, b = \pi$ and you will find out that there is no period...

Comment: For "most" *real number pairs* $(a,b)$, $f(x)$ will not be periodic. But for example when $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $f(x)$ is periodic.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions

Comment: It only works for integers. There exists no general case here. Try graphing the function on a calculator, you'll see.

Comment: @SatD: Even if $a,b$ are not rationally related, the function will be almost periodic, so noticing that $f$ is not periodic will be difficult.

Comment: See also: [Period of sum of sinusoids](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/661638).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Period of $cos(ax)$ and $sin(bx)$ are $2π/|a|$ and $2π/|b|$, respectively.
Now

> The period of the sum of two periodic functions are the **LCM** of their periods

So here the period of $f(x)= cos(ax) +  sin(bx)$ will be LCM($2π/|a|$,$2π/|b|$)

**PS**: *As other answers(or comments) pointed out this only works if $a,b \in$ $\mathbb{Z}$*

Comment: You shall note that this works only for $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Please look on this [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x%29%2Bsin%28pi+x%29+period)

Comment: yes but i think the person needs an answer for integers. (By seeing the lack of detail in the question)

Comment: I agree with you, but still believe that you should have note it.

Answer (score 3):

This has a period
if and only if
$\frac{a}{b}$
is rational.

Comment: Why? I tried to justify, but I don't know how to justify that if $h=f+g$, being $f$ of periods $p_1$ and $g$ of periods $p_2$, then for $h$ to be periodic there must be $m, n$ such that $p_1=p_2$.