# Can't get the period of the sum of a sine and a cosine

Tags: periodic-functions

$$
x(t) = 2\cos(5t+\pi/10) + 3\sin(5\pi t)
$$

I'm supposing that the signal is periodic (because sine and cosine are periodic) but then;

\begin{align}
P_{\sin} &= \tfrac{2}{5} \\
P_{\cos} &= \tfrac{2\pi}{5}
\end{align}

How can I find the period of the sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the sum is periodic, because $\pi$ is irrational. If $T$ were the period, there would exist integers $n,m$ such that $5T=n 2\pi$ and $5\pi T=m2\pi$, but then
$$\frac{5\pi T}{5T}=\frac{m2\pi}{n 2\pi}$$
or
$$\pi=\frac{m}{n}$$
$\pi$ is irrational, so this is impossible.

[See also this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661638/period-of-sum-of-sinusoids)

Answer (score 0):

**Claim 1**:  If $f$ and $g$ are periodic functions with periods $p$ and $q$, respectively, then the period of $f+g$ is $\operatorname{lcm}(p,q)$.

(Hover over the blank boxes to reveal sketches of the proofs, but try to prove them yourself first!)

> **Proof**:  Let $\ell = \operatorname{lcm}(p,q)$ with $\ell = ap = bq$.  Since $f(t+p) = f(t)$ and $g(t+q) = g(t)$ for all $t$, $$(f+g)(t+\ell) = f(t+ap)+g(t+bq) = f(t) + g(t) = (f+g)(t)$$.  Since $\ell$ is the *least* common multiple of the periods $p$ and $q$, any smaller positive value $0<\ell'<\ell$ cannot satisfy $(f+g)(t+\ell') = (f+g)(t)$.  Hence, $\ell$ is the period of $f+g$.

**Claim 2**:  The periods $\tfrac{2}{5}$ and $\tfrac{2\pi}{5}$ are incommensurable (their ratio is irrational), so they have no least common multiple.

> The ratio of the two numbers is $\pi$, which is [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational) to be irrational.  Given any two incommensurable $p$ and $q$, suppose that they have a positive common multiple; say that $ap = bq$ with $a,b \in \Bbb{Z}$.  Then, $$\frac{p}{q} = \frac{b}{a} \in \Bbb{Q},$$ contradicting the fact that $\frac{p}{q}$ is irrational.