# Summing sines of different frequencies

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a general formula for solving the following equation:
$$A \sin(Bt+C) + D \sin(Et+F) = G \sin(Ht+I)$$

All constants on the left side of the equation are known (t is a variable). Is there a formula for calculating G, H and I? Is this even solvable in general?

I searched the web and found some semi-relevant hits, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/661638/period-of-sum-of-sinusoids), but it didn't really seem to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean $G$, $H$, $I$ to be constant (i.e. independent of $t$), then the answer is No.  The sum of sinusoids of different frequencies is never a sinusoid.

Comment: Thanks. Are there solutions if we allow G, H or I to depend on t?

Comment: Sure: $G = A \sin(B t + C) + D \sin(Et+F)$, $H = 0$, $I = \pi/2$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about a general formula, but to your answer wether it is solvable in general: the function $sin(3x+4)+sin(6x+7)$ is clearly not harmonic (you can see this by simply plotting it), providing a counterexample to the statement.

Answer (score 1):

And, of course,
if $B/E$ is irrational,
the resulting curve
is not even periodic.