# Solve $6\sin x \cos 2x\ge 0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

How can I solve the following inequality:
$${6\sin x\cos 2x\ge 0}$$
Can you give me an explicit explanation of how this exercise can be understood. I have no problems with trigonometric equations, but when it comes to inequailities of this type, where I have to combine the solutions from two or more inequalities solved apart, I get really confused. Thank you!

Comment: for that inequality to hold, either both must be positive or both must be negatives, or one of them zero. you need to find the values of $x $ where that condition is satisfied.

Comment: $g(x)=sin(x)cos(2x)$ is an odd and $2\pi$-perodic function so we can solve for $x$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$ and then conclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\sin x\cos2x=0$

either $\sin x=0\implies x=n\pi$ or $\cos2x=0\implies2x$ must be odd multiple of $\dfrac\pi2$

Else we need $(1)\displaystyle\sin x>0$ and $\displaystyle\cos2x>0$ 
OR $(2)\displaystyle\sin x<0$ and $\displaystyle\cos2x<0$

For $\displaystyle(2), \pi<x<2\pi$ and $\displaystyle2m\pi+\frac\pi2<2x<2m\pi+\frac{3\pi}2\iff m\pi+\frac\pi4<x<m\pi+\frac{3\pi}4$

So, the intersection is $\displaystyle\pi+\frac\pi4<x<\pi+\frac{3\pi}4$

For $\displaystyle(1),0<x<\pi$

and $\left(2m\pi+0<2x<2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2\text{ OR  }2m\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}2<x\le2m\pi+2\pi\right)$

$\displaystyle\implies0<x<\pi\text{ and }\left(m\pi<x<m\pi+\dfrac\pi4\text{ OR  }m\pi+\dfrac{3\pi}4<x\le m\pi+\pi\right)$

Can you find the intersections?

Comment: Yes, but does not $cos2x$ have a different period($\pi$) from $sinx$($2\pi$)?How is it possible to combine two intervals with different periods?

Comment: I have one more question, because , excuse me , but I have some misunderstandings in your explanation. When $cos2x>0$ can we directly write that ${-\pi\over 2}+2\pi k\lt2x\lt{{\pi\over 2} +2\pi k}$. But this means that the period is different from that of $sinx>0$!!??

Comment: @JohnG., Now I can't understand your expression

Comment: Yes just one minute please, excuse me

Comment: So, then , how do I find the intersection of two intervals with different periods?

Comment: @JohnG., Probably this (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions) will help

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$\cos 2x=f(\sin x)$?? what is that $f$? (you can actually neglect that $6$...)

Comment: Yes, it's->   $1-2\sin^2x$

Comment: you are suppose to use that and solve it....

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$6\sin x\cos2x\geq0\iff\sin x\cos2x\geq0$ and $\cos2x=1-2\sin^{2}x$

So to be solved is $y\left(1-2y^{2}\right)\geq0$ where $y=\sin x$