# How to find the fundamental period of the product of two periodic functions?

Tags: periodic-functions

Say you wanted to find the period of $x(t)=\sin(at)\sin(bt)$ where $a$ and $b$ are real constants. How could you go about this?

Comment: se: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions?rq=1

Comment: @EmilioNovati Thank you!