# Find the period of $2\sin(2x)\cos^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I tried:

$$2\sin(2x)\cos^2(x) = \\
2\cdot\cos x\cdot\sqrt{\sin x(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)} = \\
2\cdot \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}\cdot\sqrt{\sin x (1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)} = \\
2 \cdot \sqrt{(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)\sin x (1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)} = \\
2 \cdot \sqrt{(1-\sin^2x)^2\sin x} = \\
2 \cdot (1-\sin^2x)\sqrt{\sin x} = \\???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: Does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions?

Comment: You cannot use square roots. What if you choose $x=-\pi/2$? Plus if you look at your last line, and the first line, you get $\sin(2x)=\sqrt{\sin x}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$2\sin(2x)\cos^2 x=2\sin(2x)(\cos(2x)+1)/2=\sin(2x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(4x)$$
The first term has a period of $\pi$, the second $\pi/2$, so the period for your expression is $\pi$

Comment: Could expand on your conclusion? What did you do exactly to get the period using those two periods?

Comment: Wait I think I get it, you found the first multiple of the periods right?

Comment: Correct. If I would use $\pi/2$ the first term is not the same

Answer (score 0):

Since *a* period of $f(x)=2\sin 2x\cos^2 x$ is certainly $2\pi$ and $f(x)$ vanishes at $0$, $\pi/2$, $\pi$, $3\pi/2$ and $2\pi$, in the interval $[0,2\pi]$, the *minimum* period can only be $\pi/2$ or $\pi$, if it is not $2\pi$. Clearly
$$
f(x+\pi)=2\sin(2x+2\pi)\cos^2(x+\pi)=2\sin2x(-\cos x)^2=f(x)
$$

So *a* period is $\pi$. Can $\pi/2$ be a period? Hint: look at the sign of $f$.