# Period of $\sin{2 \pi x} +\sin{\frac{\pi x}{3}} + \sin{\frac{\pi x}{5}}$ using LCM is always the shortest period?

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Individual periods are $1$, $6$ and $10$ . Their LCM is $30$ .
My question is: Is the LCM of the individual period always the shortest period of the net function ? and if not, is there a way to identify ?

In this question it is indeed the shortest period but as given in the third comment [of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions/164238#164238)

It is mentioned that it need not always be the case, how do i know if it is that case or not?

Comment: It is a period, but it need not be the fundamental/shortest period. E.g. you could have these functions sum up to 0.

Comment: true , then there is no general way to get the period of a complex function?

Comment: @CalvinLin What’s the period of $f(x)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

The period of $\sin ax$ is $2\pi/a$
The periods of individual functiona are $T_1=1, T_2=6, T_3=10$
As their LCM is 30. So the period is 30.
You may check that $f(x+T)=f(x),$for  real values of $x$, where $T=30$.
No number lesser than 30 will do so.

Yes LCM method is the shortes one but only some time it fails.
For example the period of $f(x)=\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x$. By LCM rile is $\pi$
but by trigonometric reduction $f(x)=A+B \cos 4x$ so the correct period id $\pi/2$

Trigonometric reduction  alway gives the period correctly. Here you may use $\sin C + \sin D.$ forula,

Comment: yes , but will doing LCM give me the shortest functions of all such combinations of simple functions into a big functions ? and how would you know if it is not the smalles period?

Comment: @soutrik das you may see my edit.

Comment: your example $\sin^2x-\cos^2x$ can be written as $-\cos{2x}$ which still has $\pi$ as the period but i get what you wanted to say that sometimes it cannot give the shortest period.

Comment: @sourtik das sorry it was a typo it should have been $$\sin^4 x+\cos^4 x$, you may see my edit.