# How can I find the fundamental period of the following signal?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, signal-processing

How to find the fundamental period if it is periodic?
$$
x[n] = \cos((\pi/2)n)\cos((\pi/4)n)
$$
I have simplified to the following but not sure what to do next:
$$
\cos((\pi/2)n)\cos((\pi/4)n) = 1/2[\cos((3\pi/4)n)+\cos((\pi/4)n)]
$$
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/164221/399263. Then the period is a divisor of $8$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Determine the period of $\cos\frac{3\pi}4n$ and of $\cos\frac{\pi}4n$.

The fundamental period of their sum is the l.c.m. of both periods.

Comment: The lcm of their period is a period of the sum, but the fundamental one may be smaller.

Comment: If the definition of  a period is satisfied for all $n$??

Answer (score 1):

If you simplify further expanding with the formula $\cos 3\alpha=\cos ^3(\alpha )-3 \sin ^2(\alpha ) \cos (\alpha )$ you get
$$\frac{1}{2} \cos ^3\left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right)-\frac{3}{2} \sin ^2\left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{4}\right)$$
So it's much easier to see that the period is $8$.