# The period of the given function?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, periodic-functions

I have this function for $\{\alpha,\beta,x\}>0$ and reals.
$$  \frac{\cos \left(\alpha +\frac{\beta }{2} \right)x+ \Big(5 \cos  (\alpha -\beta )x+7 \cos \beta  x-1\Big)\cos  \frac{\beta}{2}x }{\cos  \frac{\alpha}{2} x\; \cos  \frac{\beta -\alpha}{2} x }  $$
How to determine the period of this function?

Comment: mostly begin with $\alpha = 2 \gamma$ and $\beta = 2 \delta,$ so all the halves go away. Also, the function may not be periodic ( when $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ is not rational) unless there is significant cancellation; so, expand out.

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions

Answer (score 1):

You really wouldn't want to ignore the parts where it's not defined. :))) Anyhow, doing just that, note that it would be enough to find a $T > 0$ such that $\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2} x) = \cos(\frac{\alpha}{2} (x + T)),$ $\cos(\frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} x) = \cos(\frac{\beta - \alpha}{2} (x + T)),$ $\cos((\beta - \alpha) x) = \cos((\beta - \alpha) (x + T)),$ $\cos(\beta x) = \cos(\beta (x + T)),$ $\cos(\frac{\beta}{2} x) = \cos(\frac{\beta}{2} (x + T))$ and $\cos((\alpha + \frac{\beta}{2}) x) = \cos((\alpha + \frac{\beta}{2}) (x + T)).$ Note that some of these equations are redundant. Taking into consideration the periodicity of $\cos,$ we deduce that $$\begin{cases} \frac{\alpha}{2} T = 2 k \pi,\\ \frac{\beta}{2} T = 2 l \pi, \end{cases}$$ for some non-zero $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Note how the fact that all the other arguments become multiples of $2\pi$ follows immediately if only these two conditions are satisfied. Thus, we get that $T = \frac{4 k \pi}{\alpha} = \frac{4 l \pi}{\beta}$ for some non-zero $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}.$

We remark that a necessary condition for this to be possible is that the fraction $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{l}{k}$ is rational. This is also sufficient, since if $\beta = \frac{l}{k} \alpha,$ then $T := \frac{4 k \pi}{\alpha}$ is a period for the function in question. To get the smallest period provided by this line of reasoning, you compute $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ and simplify it as much as you can, getting a rational $\frac{l}{k}$ with $(l, k) = 1$ and then simply define $T:= \frac{4 k \pi}{\alpha}.$

Is this **THE** period of the function though? It may not be, the expression of the function is pretty gnarly, but maybe it can in fact be simplified to something simple, a function whose period is easily computed. Anyhow, this is more of a brute force algorithm. Nevertheless, a period does indeed appear.

Comment: I mean simplify the resulting fraction (you are in the case where $\frac{\beta}{\alpha}$ is a non-zero rational). As a toy example, suppose $\beta = 36, \, \alpha = 42.$ You get $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{36}{42}$ and simplifying it as much as you can you get $\frac{\beta}{\alpha} = \frac{6}{7},$ so, with the notation used in the answer, you take $l = 6$ and $k = 7.$