# Predicting Fundamental period

Tags: calculus, periodic-functions

I've been studing the periodic functions and i was just wondering how to calculate the fundamental period for functions like :
|sin(x)|+ |cos(x)|

Which the value of LCM is a period of function but not fundamental period
, So i was just looking for a way to predict it without ploting it
and also it seems in these types of functions fundamental period is half of value of LCM
, is it correct ?

Comment: Wouldn't you expect any describable process to give the same period to $|\sin x| + |\cos x|$ and to $|\sin(x+\pi/2)| - |\cos(x)|$?  You might want to graph that last one...

Comment: Nice ! it becomes zero and there is no fundamental period ... but there is a trigonometric approach to this  because $|\sin(x+\pi/2)| = |\cos(x)|$ but what about the function which i asked ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164221/period-of-the-sum-product-of-two-functions#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20suppose%20to,LCM(a%2Cb).